# How to fix: 'e is not a function' error in react-redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to make a simple login form in **react-native** using **redux** in the **expo**. 
I followed some tutorial and redux docs they all do it in this way but I face this error every time:
 
**e is not a function** 
TypeError: e is not a function

snack link: https://snack.expo.io/@housein/reduxtest

code:

'App.js':

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
  render () {
    const store = createStore(reducers);
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View>
          <LoginForm />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

'components/LoginForm.js':

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';
import actions from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  onEmailChange(text) {
    return this.props.emailChanged(text);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Text >Email:</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
          value={this.props.e}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {e : state.auth.email};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(LoginForm);
```

'actions/index.js':

```
export const emailChanged = (text) => {
  return {
    type: 'EMAIL_CHANGED',
    payload: text
  };
};
```

'reducers/index.js':

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth : AuthReducer
});
```

'reducers/AuthReducer.js':

```
const INIT_STATE = {email : ''}

export default (state=INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'EMAIL_CHANGED' : 
      return {...state, email  : action.payload};
    default : 
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: which line of the code you posted is responsible?

Comment: Why are you doing binding inside`onChangeText` of `TextInput` ? It should be done in constructor or use arrow function

Comment: thank you, guys. the 'second' thing has been removed was a mistake but not the case.

Comment: This works if you set `"react-redux": "6.0.1"` in your package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is when using mapStateToProps the **web version of "snack.expo" through an error "e" is not a function .  You must check it in Android or Ios**

Couple of small changes i have made

**Define actions like this**

```
import {emailChanged} from '../actions';
const actions = {
  emailChanged: emailChanged
};
```

**Add flex:1 to main component**

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
          <LoginForm />
        </View>
```

snack link : https://snack.expo.io/@mehran.khan/reduxtest

App Preview on ANDROID

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your right it's working fine in ios. and better to deconstruct actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to spread the `actions` like that..

```
mapDispatchToProps = () => { ... actions };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentName);
```

That being said, there are some thing I do not like in your AuthReducer. What does that line do exactly..??

```
return {...state, email  : 'second'};
```

I would change it to:

```
return {...state, email  : action.payload};
```

Also in your combine reducers function:

```
export default reducers = () => combineReducers({
  auth : AuthReducer
});
```

Try those out. I think it will solve your problems. Although, I think I am missing something.

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that he creates the store in every render of the App component instead of creating it globally.

Comment: Hhmmm, quite right .. I missed that. And I thought something was looking funny in that component. Nice catch...

Comment: mapDispatchToProps didn't work. tried that before. I've been told passing this argument as an object is ok because redux automatically will dispatch the passed action

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there with LoginForm component.

The onChangeText prop is expecting a function. You need bind your emailChanged method in constructor or use arrow function.
You don't need to return anything from onEmailChange method.

There is a problem in the reducer code as well.

'components/LoginForm.js':

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';
import actions from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.onEmailChange = this.onEmailChange.bind(this);
  }

  onEmailChange(text) {
    this.props.emailChanged(text);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Text >Email:</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={this.onEmailChange}
          value={this.props.e}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {e : state.auth.email};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(LoginForm);
```

'reducers/AuthReducer.js':

```
const INIT_STATE = {email : ''}

export default (state=INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'EMAIL_CHANGED' : 
      return {...state, email: action.payload };
    default : 
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved but not in a favorable way. 
added `mapDispatchToProps` and pass it as the second argument of `connect(,)()`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    emailChanged : (text) => dispatch({
      type: 'EMAIL_CHANGED',
      payload: text
    })
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

and obviously removed `import actions from '../actions';`
but when action list gets too long, it's gonna be weired to use them like this!